# Division with remainder with positive remainder

Tags: c++, c++20, modulo

Let `a, b` be real numbers with `b != 0`. I want to perform division with remainder of `a` by `b`. The result should be the unique real number `r` contained in `[0, |b|)` such that `a = bc + r` for some (unique) integer `c`.

`std::fmod` yields a similar result, but it allows `r` to be negative. For example, `std::fmod(-.1, 1) == -.1`, but I need a function which yields `0.9` for this example.

Answer (score 2):

You could build your own pretty easily:

```
double pos_fmod(double a, double b) {
    double mod_val = std::fmod(a, b);
    return mod_val >= 0 ? mod_val : b + mod_val;
}
```

Note that this assumes `b > 0`.